# Transpose rows to columns dynamically in mySql

Tags: mysql, dynamic, pivot-table

I wanted to display monthly attendance of an employee in one single row for 30 days. it should contains day wise Time In and Time Out.

Please help me in solving this .

My table contains following data

```
Insert into staff values (1,'Srinivas','Training');

Insert into staff values (2,'Govada','Training');



Create table Bio 
(
Bio_id int Not Null AUTO_INCREMENT,
Staff_id Int Not Null,
DateIn Datetime ,
DateOut Datetime,
CONSTRAINT Bio_pk PRIMARY KEY (Bio_id)
);

--First Employee

Insert into Bio values (1,1,'2020-08-01 09:00:00','2020-08-01 16:00:00');
Insert into Bio values (2,1,'2020-08-02 09:00:00','2020-08-02 16:00:00');
Insert into Bio values (3,1,'2020-08-03 09:00:00','2020-08-03 16:00:00');
Insert into Bio values (4,1,'2020-08-04 09:00:00','2020-08-04 16:00:00');
Insert into Bio values (5,1,'2020-08-05 09:00:00','2020-08-05 16:00:00');
Insert into Bio values (6,1,'2020-08-06 09:00:00','2020-08-06 16:00:00');
Insert into Bio values (7,1,'2020-08-07 09:00:00','2020-08-07 16:00:00');
Insert into Bio values (8,1,'2020-08-08 09:00:00','2020-08-08 16:00:00');
Insert into Bio values (9,1,'2020-08-09 09:00:00','2020-08-09 16:00:00');
Insert into Bio values (10,1,'2020-08-10 09:00:00','2020-08-10 16:00:00');
```

--SecondEmployee

```
Insert into Bio values (11,2,'2020-08-01 09:00:00','2020-08-01 16:00:00');
Insert into Bio values (12,2,'2020-08-02 09:00:00','2020-08-02 16:00:00');
Insert into Bio values (13,2,'2020-08-03 09:00:00','2020-08-03 16:00:00');
Insert into Bio values (14,2,'2020-08-04 09:00:00','2020-08-04 16:00:00');
Insert into Bio values (15,2,'2020-08-05 09:00:00','2020-08-05 16:00:00');
Insert into Bio values (16,2,'2020-08-06 09:00:00','2020-08-06 16:00:00');
Insert into Bio values (17,2,'2020-08-07 09:00:00','2020-08-07 16:00:00');
Insert into Bio values (18,2,'2020-08-08 09:00:00','2020-08-08 16:00:00');
Insert into Bio values (19,2,'2020-08-09 09:00:00','2020-08-09 16:00:00');
Insert into Bio values (20,2,'2020-08-10 09:00:00','2020-08-10 16:00:00');
```

Data in table using query

```
SELECT Staff_id as id
     , date_format(Datein, '%Y-%m-%d') as date
     , date_format(Datein, '%H-%i') as TimeIn
     , date_format(DateOut, '%H-%i') as TimeOut
   FROM Bio 
 group 
    by Staff_id
     , date(Datein);


Staff_id     AttDate           TimeIn      Time Out
1         2020-08-01     09-00  16-00
1         2020-08-02    09-00   16-00
1         2020-08-03    09-00   16-00
1         2020-08-04    09-00   16-00
1         2020-08-05    09-00   16-00
1         2020-08-06    09-00   16-00
1         2020-08-07    09-00   16-00
1         2020-08-08    09-00   16-00
1         2020-08-09    09-00   16-00
1         2020-08-10    09-00   16-00
2         2020-08-01    09-00   16-00
2         2020-08-02    09-00   16-00
2         2020-08-03    09-00   16-00
2         2020-08-04    09-00   16-00
2         2020-08-05    09-00   16-00
2         2020-08-06    09-00   16-00
2         2020-08-07    09-00   16-00
2         2020-08-08    09-00   16-00
2         2020-08-09    09-00   16-00
2         2020-08-10    09-00   16-00
```

Desired output : To display each staff daily in and out time in one row for entire month.

```
----------
Staff_id        2020-08-01               2020-08-02         2020-08-03  
----------
1               09:00    16:00           09:00    16:00      09:00  16:00
```

Please help me in writing the query in MySQL

thanks

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code, and note that in the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is never appropriate.

Comment: @Strawberry  Thanks for the suggestion. I really need to tweak in to get the query working. It worked in SQL Server with Pivot. Unable to do this with MySQL.  Please share your ideas for solving this